# SSDT database project as data source for Tabular SSAS project?

Tags: database-project, ssas-tabular

Can I use a SSDT database project as a datasource for a Tabular SSAS project?
I am using a visual studio solution to build and maintain multiple projects, sql database projects, ssis packages and I want to add an SSAS tabular project as well, but is there a way I can build the ssas model using the table structure in the database project as a data source? once I deploy the ssas project, I will specify a connection to a live database, but build against a structure, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. But if you're not afraid of writing some kind of script/program, it should be doable.

Your best option would be to deploy the SSDT database project somewhere, and then use the various DMV's (sys.tables, sys.columns, sys.foreign_keys), etc. to collect the information you need to generate the Tabular Model.

You could then get creative with the [TOM AMO library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo) using PowerShell or C#, to build the Tabular model based on the information collected from the DMV's. It won't be easy, but if your database follows a strict naming convention, it should be doable.

Good luck!